# npm install react-navigation-stack@^1.10.3 gives error

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-stack

I installed react-navigation v4 and now I want to install `react-navigation-stack@^1.10.3`

So I ran `npm install react-navigation-stack@^1.10.3`
and this is the message I got:

```
npm WARN deprecated react-navigation-stack@1.10.3: This version of React Navigation Stack is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 2.x.x. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x#react-navigation-stack for instructions. 
npm WARN react-navigation-stack@1.10.3 requires a peer of react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: file-uri-to-path@1.0.0 (node_modules\file-uri-to-path):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\file-uri-to-path' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.file-uri-to-path.DELETE'        
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: nan@2.14.1 (node_modules\nan):
npm WARN enoent SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\nan' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.nan.DELETE'

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\react-navigation-stack
npm ERR! dest C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.react-navigation-stack.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\react-navigation-stack' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.react-navigation-stack.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\yaelp\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-02T15_41_49_774Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Try upgrading your `react-navigation-stack` version to 2.x.x, as it says in the first message:

> This version of React Navigation Stack is no longer supported. Please upgrade to 2.x.x. See https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/upgrading-from-3.x#react-navigation-stack for instructions.

Or try installing it like that:

`npm install react-navigation-stack@2.8.4`

I wouldn't recommend you installing deprecated libraries even if you really want to, because usually there is a big reason behind when some package version goes deprecated.

From the link above:

> Note: The alpha versions for 2.0 used Reanimated for the animations. We've replaced Reanimated with React Native's Animated API in the stable release. If you did any custom animations with the alpha, please migrate your code to the Animated API.

Comment: @sheepsbleat What does it output when you try running the above command? You can also try `npm install react-navigation-stack`

Comment: npm install react-navigation-stack gives sthe same error
and 
it gives me this error: npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\react-navigation-stack' -> 'C:\Users\yaelp\Downloads\meals-cat\node_modules\.react-navigation-stack.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.